# ld+json formatting error formatting

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to write code for google structured data but there's an error on line 13 `],` at the end of `sameAs`

Here's the json

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.kenyabuzz.com",
      "logo": "http://www.kenyabuzz.com/media/cache/0f/93/0f9352f94002226ad2e57fdf4cda378a.jpg",

      "sameAs" : [
        "https://www.facebook.com/KenyaBuzz",
        "https://twitter.com/KenyaBuzz",
        "http://instagram.com/kenyabuzz_",
        "http://blog.kenyabuzz.com/",
      ],

      "contactPoint" : [{
        "@type" : "ContactPoint",
        "telephone" : "+254773809556",
        "contactType" : "customer service",
        "areaServed" : "KE"
      }]

    }


</script>
```

It's for google structure data and can be tested here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: `"http://blog.kenyabuzz.com/",` -> remove comma . valid as Javascript but not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `,` from line number 12.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.kenyabuzz.com",
      "logo": "http://www.kenyabuzz.com/media/cache/0f/93/0f9352f94002226ad2e57fdf4cda378a.jpg",

      "sameAs" : [
        "https://www.facebook.com/KenyaBuzz",
        "https://twitter.com/KenyaBuzz",
        "http://instagram.com/kenyabuzz_",
        "http://blog.kenyabuzz.com/"
      ],

      "contactPoint" : [{
        "@type" : "ContactPoint",
        "telephone" : "+254773809556",
        "contactType" : "customer service",
        "areaServed" : "KE"
      }]

    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try online parsers like http://json.parser.online.fr/ , which gives:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 12 column 7 of the JSON data
```

then you immediately see the comma pointed out in preceding answers ;-)

Comment: or to be a bit more precise: it indicates an error on the following `]` character, because it's awaiting data following the comma